# SQL for SQLite: Sorting not working with null columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, sorting

The following is my sql statement for SQLite:

```
Select UGM.*, C.Name, C.ChatName From
UserGroupMembers UGM Inner Join Contacts C On C.ContactID = UGM.MemberID
Where (UGM.OwnerID = ?) And (UGM.UserGroupID = ?)
Order By COALESCE(C.Name, C.ChatName)
```

The table Contacts contains a Name and ChatName column. If the Name column is not null, then the data from this column is used in the sorting. If it is Null, then the data from the ChatName is to be used instead. Both columns will never be null at the same time.

The sql statement does return the correct rows but it is never sorted properly. Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `IFULL()` instead of `COALESCE()` to see if it returns the same?

Comment: @mwan means `IFNULL` of course.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use ifnull in this sql statement. I've checked other examples in stackoverflow but can't find anything that applies to mine. Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: @Polaris: Just substitute it for `COALESCE`, ie `Order By IFNULL(C.Name, C.ChatName)`

Comment: I tried that but it generates a "syntax error". All the examples I've seen uses ifnull in the WHERE clause but not after the SORT clause.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks for spotting that! ;-) I reread my comment after yours and my brain kept fixing it so I couldn't see the typo. :P I did of course mean `IFNULL`

Comment: @Polaris431 Can you post the SQL you were using?  I just tried using `IFNULL` in the `ORDER BY` clause on my local version of SQLite, and it worked correctly.  For reference, my test statement looked like this: `SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY IFNULL(name, charname);`

Comment: Are you sure the columns are actually null and not empty strings?

Comment: They are indeed null. I was able to use ifnull but as follows:

Select UGM.*, lower(ifnull(Name, ChatName)) As CName From
UserGroupMembers UGM Inner Join Contacts C On C.ContactID = UGM.MemberID
Where (UGM.OwnerID = ?) And (UGM.UserGroupID = ?)
Order By CName Asc

Without the "lower" function, it will not sort. This is strange considering that the columns Name and ChatName are both designed with "TEXT collate nocase".

Comment: Your example above will work if the order statement is changed to this: Order By COALESCE(lower(Name), lower(ChatName))

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this :

```
Select * from (
  Select UGM.*, C.Name, C.ChatName, COALESCE(C.Name, C.ChatName) as Sorting 
    From UserGroupMembers UGM 
    Inner Join Contacts C On C.ContactID = UGM.MemberID
    Where (UGM.OwnerID = ?) And (UGM.UserGroupID = ?))
) Order By Sorting
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not sort correctly. The solution I provided above does, for some mysterious reason. I have a feeling that the version of SQLite that is running on my version of Android (2.2) has a bug in how it handles null columns using COALESCE or IFNULL.

Comment: I tested it on a MacBook, how does it not sort correctly? I am curious.